# How to just pass parameters to a method without running when the first call, and run it without parameters when call it again?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For some reason, I hope when i first call method test(), it just pass parameters, but when i call it(`without parameters`) again, it will run.

I know using self.a, self.b will be a choice, but i don't want the parameters to be instance properties.

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.test(a=1, b=2)          # I hope this doesn't call method test but pass parameters 

    def test(self, a=None, b=None):
        print('in test')
        return a, b
        
    def get_from_test(self):
        return self.test()      # I hope it can run without parameters


f = Foo()
t = f.get_from_test()
print(t)
```

Comment: XY problem: you probably just need to define 2 class attributes: `self._a` and `self._b` and reuse them in `test`. Do you need to run `test` with parameters at some point?

Comment: Thanks your reminding, but i don't want the parameters to be instance properties.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._a, self._b = None, None
        self.test(a=1, b=2)
    def test(self, a=None, b=None):
        if a is None:
            a = self._a
        else:
            self._a = a
        if b is None:
            b = self._b
        else:
            self._b = b
        return a, b
```

So basically every time you call `test` by setting `a` and/or `b`, their values are kept in memory so that they can be reused later. Example:

```
f = Foo()
print(f.test()) # 1, 2
print(f.test(b=4)) # 1, 4
print(f.test()) # 1, 4
print(f.test(a=3)) # 3, 4
print(f.test()) # 3, 4
print(f.test(2, 7)) # 2, 7
print(f.test()) # 2, 7
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to initialize default values for a & b. Then if the parameters aren't specified (i.e. are `None`, use default)

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._default_a=1
        self._default_b=2

    def test(self, a=None, b=None):
        print('in test')
        return a if a is not None else self._default_a, b if b is not None else self._default_b

    def get_from_test(self):
        return self.test()      # I hope it can run without parameters


f = Foo()
t = f.get_from_test()
print(t)
```